# Any way to fit Bootstrap modals to window size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site using Bootstrap 2.3 and I'm using the modal function as a lightbox for my images.

Is there anyway to fit the modal to height of the users screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/fUZxA/23/?

Comment: That is what I want, but I need the picture to resize with it. Sorry to ask (still new to web dev) but could you explain what code actually makes it resize, I tried adding the last bit of javascript to my site (subbing in my classes where necessary) and couldn't get it to work :/

Comment: Might as well post my actual site as it's up for testing. [shifteddd](http://www.shifteddd.com)

Comment: You need to preserve ratio for the image to look correct. Why can't you just change: `width: 596px;` to `width:auto;` in your `.poster-image-lb` class?

Comment: I solved it using `height: 90vh`. Thanks for your help!